# Modify dropdown box and radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a long page that asks questions and makes a grand total score at the bottom.

If I type numbers in text fields they work fine being added to the grand total, but I have some radio buttons and a dropdown box that don't work when selected (ie. they don't tally to the grand total)

The script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".txt").each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 0 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
    }
```

The html:

```
        <p>Select weight:<br />
          Underweight (-1 point)<input class="txt" type="radio" name="weight" value="-1" /><br />
          Normal weight (+1 point)<input class="txt" type="radio" name="weight" value="+1" checked="checked" /><br />
          Underweigth (-1 point)<input class="txt" type="radio" name="weight" value="-1" />
        </p>

        <p>Select vision impairment: 
          <select id="heath-status">
            <option class="txt" value="1">Normal and healthy (+1)</option>
            <option class="txt" value="-1">Mild impairment (-1)</option>
            <option class="txt" value="-2">Moderate impairment (-2)</option>
            <option class="txt" value="-3">Moderate/Severe impairment (-3)</option>
            <option class="txt" value="-4">Severe impairment (-4)</option>
            <option class="txt" value="-5">Severe/Extreme impairment (-5)</option>
            <option class="txt" value="-6">Extreme impairment (-6)</option>
          </select>
          </p>
        <p>Enter number of limbs you have (1 point for each limb): <input class="txt" type="text"/></p>

        <p>Enter number of days per week you exercise (1 point for each day): <input class="txt" type="text"/></p>

        <p>Grand total health score: <span id="sum">0</span></p>
```

Half working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hMgpM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("input.txt:checked, select .txt:selected, input.txt:not(:radio)").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseInt(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

Basically you weren't selecting the right fields for the sum.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hMgpM/1/

EDIt - to have things work better you should also do

```
        $(this).bind("click keyup", function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
```

instead of

```
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hMgpM/3/

Comment: Thanks Nicola, any chance you know how to add the radio and dropdown box selections to the grand total?

Comment: Awesome stuff, thanks again Nicola, both you and James really helped.

Comment: @Dan i already added everything and i my edit i added the event olso on the other elements

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/hMgpM/7/

A number of things here.  You don't want the class on each individual `<option>` but rather the `select`.  You were summing all options rather than just the selected one.  Similarly, radio buttons need to be handled differently in order to only sum the selected ones.

Also, you will want to sum, not just on typing but also on selecting a radio button or changing the value of the select box.  You can also clean that up a bit by getting rid of the wrapper function since you can just pass the function directly.  Also, the `each` was unneeded.  When calling something like `keyup`, it will bind to all elements in your jquery object, so no need to loop.

```
<p>Select weight:<br />
    Underweight (-1 point)<input class="rad" type="radio" name="weight" value="-1" /><br />
    Normal weight (+1 point)<input class="rad" type="radio" name="weight" value="+1" checked="checked" /><br />
    Underweigth (-1 point)<input class="rad" type="radio" name="weight" value="-1" />
</p>

<p>Select vision impairment: 
    <select id="heath-status" class="txt">
        <option  value="1">Normal and healthy (+1)</option>
        <option  value="-1">Mild impairment (-1)</option>
        <option  value="-2">Moderate impairment (-2)</option>
        <option  value="-3">Moderate/Severe impairment (-3)</option>
        <option  value="-4">Severe impairment (-4)</option>
        <option  value="-5">Severe/Extreme impairment (-5)</option>
        <option  value="-6">Extreme impairment (-6)</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>Enter number of limbs you have (1 point for each limb): <input class="txt" type="text"/></p>

<p>Enter number of days per week you exercise (1 point for each day): <input class="txt" type="text"/></p>

<p>Grand total health score: <span id="sum">0</span></p>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $("input.txt").keyup(calculateSum);
    $("select.txt").change(calculateSum);
    $(".rad").click(calculateSum);

    calculateSum();
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    $(".rad:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

Comment: Impressive work, thanks James. I have to figure out how to tally the score on the page load rather that having to activate it by typing in the text box.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use `$('name=[weight] :checked')` instead. This will give you just one radio button that is checked and you don't have to do another `$.each` with an if statement.

Comment: Updated with `:checked`.  Also, you can just call your method in `document.ready` and it will calculate on load.

Comment: I noticed that update, top notch job. Going to bed now, it's 3am.